# XXE file disclosure vulnerability prevention

Tags: asp.net, webforms, xxe

I have XXE file disclosure vulnerability in my asp.net application but there is no xml data that i dealing with in my application. Please help me with changes i have to implement to prevent this vulnerability.

Comment: How do you know you have one?

Comment: through a scan that was done on my application, but we were not given details about the page where vulnerability was detected

Comment: I recommand you to read the XXE.Prevention sheet from OWASP to see if you use one of the class/method listed for your .NET. This casn be a first start point. The sheet is at https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md